# How i can call more than one Api in single Activity using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use two URL in my project to fetch data using volley in two or more different activity. How should I do? Please give me some code or explain me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you give me some code or link please?

Comment: are you trying to fetch data from APIs?

Comment: yes  through apis

Comment: there are plenty of examples on internet like https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-fetch-json/  i would recommond use Retrofit instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow steps in this tutorial, by this you will be able to completely implement volley in your project. Here is link [volley tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/parsing-json-android-using-volley-library/)

Just use this method in again second activity for fetching second url:

```
 // Creating the JsonObjectRequest class called obreq, passing required parameters: 
 //GET is used to fetch data from the server, JsonURL is the URL to be fetched from. 
 JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(R......
```

Comment: do i have to make another adapter file or can i use previous one?

Comment: If data holder are same for both list so you will use same adapter for both...and fetching of data from volley is independent of adapter.